# working with JTATransactionManager in spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, java-ee-7

I am trying to use `JtaTransactionManager` in spring/hibernate. I have below configuration.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">  
    <property name="userTransactionName" value="java:comp/UserTransaction"></property>  
</bean>
```

Now can i mark my service methods with `@Transactional` ? or do i need any extra configuration to use `@Transactional` ? do i need to add  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An annotation is nothing more then metadata, so only slapping an annotation on there and expect it to magically work isn't going to happen.

To make `@Transactional` work you need to tell spring that you want to use annotation to drive your transactions. For this add the `<tx:annotation-driven />` tag to your configuration.

However that probably isn't going to be all there is needed as you also need to configure hibernate appropriately for JTA.

A small tip instead of defining the bean, use the shorter `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />`. This will do some detection on which app server you are running and configure the appropriate transaction manager for you. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-application-server-integration for more information.

Comment: Deinum, could you please provide some sample spring configuration if you have handy

Comment: configuration for what? How to configure hibernate depends on your JTA implementation/appserver.

Comment: I am deploying the Application in tomcat. But it has to do jndi look up in another JBoss App server for UserTransaction.

Comment: Now i have this code.  InitialContext initialContext = someBean.getInitialContext();  UserTransaction tx = (UserTransaction)initialContext.lookup("UserTransaction");tx.begin();............tx.commit();

Comment: Configure the lookup in the Spring application context (using `<jee:jndi-lookup ... />` and inject the result into the `JtaTransactionManager`.